# Os X crashed using Sublime Text. Html is now malformed binary

Tags: html, crash, binary, sublimetext3

While I was coding, my computer crashed. Now when i look at my files i see malformed binary output.

```
ú…|Y«Ó4◊©{zû¯ÄåÊA=˝‹.Ö®Å»ÂsıØ6ÌÀäÆj
—·Ks5‡ó‹≤ŸV/F6“ÎøõH
a$K“áÒE›£á‰ï™B–ü™‘Xnn∂{!˜ãzNÈ·„ˆ´êk•iQ≠¡<’√àKú@Ê√u¶îÕõî éË∏7Á¸oLx‘3∫Ø4Ìè´«(K
‚™9«øÚâŒØjÒˇzQöº{vZ¸^EÎIä?ïä;˜ø∂pw!A†∑®ﬂY∑ºóÓÉu:cÈ‰˘/%nbZ¶/¡ò•gA4
∂6Ü‚¬/IÉObÜáZ¿ÿäØ˛KU’ﬂ9‘úÓÜiS.tUßQ‰·a|Ï30me|
ç–V˙8tm˛∑\ıõ}˚†¯‹˝&gE9,Î©Ó<Y` k5îŸgV]Ìu 6u4‘O)Œè`‚¬=˜6«m¨m◊Ï` ãﬂøΩÜq»ÖDà,≤¨ﬁÜ˜
èRí‰yﬂΩ|˘u≥È«ﬁ’H§Õ…]ΩÓH#|6÷ié∑3|ˆS…Á6=∆q`-ãïΩçEª”>N7W™.}'πáQkOﬂ¸‚O“D1Õu¯lBp˚iN‘ïß9>ı‡»5Q   ≤y|O:    
‚áπjÂ<¸√`”c¶`∂’¸öHÔ20∑ÅD[«◊ó±\Ö€üdÿˆ/Y3·Ag®5ä≠Œ≤3¶µ~X
,±kãç≥´~É¯î⁄˝öGiÓ¨·
```

How can i fix this, any ideas ?

By the way i am using Mac OsX 10.10 Yosemite, and Sublime text 3 without any plugins.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report in somebody else's software.